# Proving subgroup of $SO(2)$ with $n$ elements is unique?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, orthogonal-matrices

I was thinking of taking two subgroups with $n$ elements and showing that they both are the same subgroup.

I know that if $M$ ($2\times2$ matrix)  is any element of $SO(2)$, $M^{-1} = M^t$. And $\det M =1$.

I don't know how to proceed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How to proceed depends on what you know about SO(2). Can you comment on that?

Comment: Do you have a candidate for this unique subgroup? (Hint: What rotation applied to itself $n$ times is the identity?)

Comment: @ChrisCulter: Added the information I know

Comment: @eepperly16: No candidates.. I need to prove, given any positive integer n, there is exactly one subgroup of SO(2) containing n elements

Comment: You want to prove that there is only one subgroup $H$ of $SO(2)$ containing $n$ elements. If you can guess $H$, your life will be a lot easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can think of $\mathrm{SO}(2)$ as the unit circle under complex multiplication. Therefore, for any point $g_i$ in your group, you get a real number $t_i$ such that $e^{it_i}=g_i$. In other words, consider this map:

$$\varphi: (\mathbb{R},+) \to (\mathbb{C}^{\times},\cdot)\cong\mathrm{SO}(2)$$

where $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ is the unit circle in the plane. This is an epimorphism of groups, i.e. it is surjective and it is a homomorphism.

Now since your subgroup of $\mathrm{SO}(2)$ is finite, take $g_i$ to be the element with the smallest $|t_i|$ in $\mathbb{R}$. In other words:

$$g_i = \varphi(\min\{t_j\in [0,2\pi): t_j=\varphi^{-1}(\{g_j\}) \})$$
 Show that $g_i$ generates your group. The proof is similar to when you want to prove that any subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ is generated by a $m \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Once you have shown that your subgroup is generated by $g_i$ and therefore it is cyclic, note that any two cyclic groups of the same order are isomorphic. And that ends the proof.